# get selected option select element id in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to fire an event of select element option selected while document is ready I use following code but it return undefined value of `option:seleted` please help.

```
$("option:selected").ready(function(){
    alert($(this).val());//use to get seleted option value
    alert($(this).parent().val());//use to get selected option value using select
    alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));//use to get select element id of selected:option
});
```

every time its give undefined

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() { // you test if document is ready
  if ($("option:selected").length > 0) {
    // your code 
    alert($("option:selected").val());//use to get seleted option value
    alert($("option:selected").parent().val());//use to get selected option value using select
    alert($("option:selected").parent().attr("id"));//use to get select element id of selected:option
  }
});
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqtu6y58/1/)